# System.FormatException: 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.'

Tags: c#, sql-server

I keep getting the error in the title when i am trying to pass data to my database using a c# windows form.

For reference, I am trying to use the **Scope_Identity** to get the current **PK** from one table and then pass it to another table as a **FK**. But i am having trouble making this work. I have no doubt I am missing something or doing something wrong, but I honestly cannot find a solution to what I need. Here is the code I am using.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"");
        con.Open();
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT dbo.Booking(CustomerID,VehicleID,DateofBooking," +
                "DurationBooked, ExpectedReturnDate) VALUES( @CustID, @VehicleID, @DOBooking, @DurationBooked,@ExpectedReturn); INSERT dbo.Payments (BookingID,PaymentMethod,Discount,PaymentAmount," +
                "PaymentDate,PaymentReceived) VALUES( SCOPE_IDENTITY(),@PayMeth,@PayAmount,@PayDate, @PayReceived, @Discount)"))

            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox1.ValueMember;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VehicleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = comboBox2.ValueMember;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOBooking", SqlDbType.Date).Value = datefrom.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpectedReturn", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTo.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DurationBooked", SqlDbType.Float, 3).Value = Duration.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayMeth", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = listBox1.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayAmount", SqlDbType.Money).Value = PayAmount.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DatePay.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayReceived", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = PayReceived.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.SmallMoney).Value = Discount.Text;

            }
```

I am having a ridiculous amount of hassle trying to Pass this **PK** to another Table as a **FK** For reference, it is the **BookingID** from the Booking table that i am trying to pass to the **Payments table** in the **BookingID** column which is a **FK** relationship

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53oYZ.png)

Comment: Are you certain you are focused on the correct element within your code? `...Add("@DurationBooked", SqlDbType.NChar)` looks suspicious. Same thought applies to `@VehicleID`. It is also odd that you have both nchar and varchar columns (presumably)

Comment: Post your table defintiions

Comment: You are correct about the @VehicleID, thats an oversight by me as i am using a combo box i am retrieving the value member from a data table. As for Duration booked, i just matched what i have in SQL server as its a numerical value.

Comment: Would doing it in one command link the PK from Booking table with the FK in the Payments table?

Comment: @AaronBertrand fair point, I have changed it.

Comment: SQL Server is never going to produce any error message that includes `Int32`, since that's a .NET type. By a process of elimination we can fairly easily conclude that the problem lies with `comboBox1.ValueMember` and/or `comboBox2.ValueMember`, since those are the only `INT` parameters, and not the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Adding explicit types to your parameters is good, but you must then still also remember to make sure you pass the correct types as values. Relying on implicit conversions, whether on the .NET side or the SQL side, is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED. Thank you to all those who helped. The issue was indeed with my Parameters, specifically with dates. I needed to change the DataType in SQL server to **DateTime**, as well as ensuring the query would run in SQL Server first helped.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT dbo.Booking(CustomerID,VehicleID,DateofBooking, DurationBooked, ExpectedReturnDate) " +
                "VALUES( @CustID, @VehicleID, @DOBooking, @DurationBooked,@ExpectedReturn) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); " +
                "INSERT dbo.Payments (BookingID,PaymentMethod,Discount,PaymentAmount, PaymentDate,PaymentReceived)" +
                "VALUES( SCOPE_IDENTITY(),@PayMeth,@Discount,@PayAmount, @PayDate, @PayReceived)"))

            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(CustID.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@VehicleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(VehicleID.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOBooking", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateofBooking.Value.Date;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpectedReturn", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = ExpectedReturnDate.Value.Date;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@DurationBooked", SqlDbType.Float, 3).Value = Duration.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayMeth", SqlDbType.VarChar, 15).Value = PaymentMethod.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayAmount", SqlDbType.Money).Value = PayAmount.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = PayDate.Value.Date;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@PayReceived", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = Received.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Discount", SqlDbType.VarChar, 3).Value = Discount.Text;
                if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Record inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Customer failed");
                }
```

For Ref, **Scope_Identity** worked perfectly.

Thanks for all your support, I know this may seem basic for some of you, but i am new to all this and trying to self teach, so as you can imagine.. it was a relief even this little issue is solved. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to fight with a different problem.
you have conversion issue, but not PK or FK key consistency.

please check if all the params they you send have the same type as described in your instruction.

It can be also that even your scope_identity() has type different from value.
I don't know if you covered this with Keys constraints

by the way. out of scope. There is also a way to get last id is to use @@IDENTITY.

The @@identity function returns the last identity created in the same session. The scope_identity() function returns the last identity created in the same session and the same scope.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your advice, i will check all the params as you suggested. As for the Scope part, i am getting a bit confused now. So when i click the button, it will send information to TWO different tables, however the second table needs to contain the PK from the first table as a FK. But other than having to query the dbs first to get the PK that was created in one table, i am not sure how i can get it to transfer as a FK into the other table.